# How to reporting all errors configuration in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had a line in CI's `autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Because of this I was getting a blank page. When I removed the `'database'`, option then I started getting the output.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of CI. For < 2.x edit the top level index.php and adjust the error_reporting function to use E_ALL"

error_reporting(E_ALL);

For >= 2.x edit the top level index.php and make sure ENVIRONMENT is set as:

define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
which sets the error_reporting to E_ALL.